# Two fields don't get saved after submitting form. Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have two model fields (hobbies and languages) that don't get saved when the user submits the form. They are many to many fields connected to separate models. But I'm not sure how to have them save in the model.

This is the model:

```
# this is model for user
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

    hobbies = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)

    profilepic = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images/Profile Pictures', blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    average_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ratings_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Uncomment if you don't want the slug to change every time the name changes
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is the Hobby and Language models:

```
# this is the model for hobbies - one to many relationship with User
class Hobby(models.Model):
    hobby = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if self.id is None:
        # self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.slug = slugify(self.hobby)
        super(Hobby, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hobby

# this is the model for languages - one to many relationship with User
class Language(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if self.id is None:
        # self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.slug = slugify(self.language)
        super(Language, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.language
```

This is the view that saves the form data into the database:

```
def createprofile(request):

    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST, instance = user)

        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)



        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user



            if 'profilepic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profilepic = request.FILES['profilepic']

            profile.save()

            registered = True

            if 'next' in request.GET:
                return redirect(request.GET['next'])

        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors



    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    return render(request,
            'createprofile.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered} )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using commit=False in your save method, Django provides a save_m2m method to create the relation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

As stated by Django docs at the link above:

> Another side effect of using commit=False is seen when your model has a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the database.